# Eigenvalue Problem - Nullspace Basis

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues

I need to solve an eigenvalue problem where some of the eigenvalues are 0. Due to the fact that I just need the eigenvectors associated to the 0-eigenvalues in some cases I'd just like to calculate the Nullspace Basis of the matrix itself instead of the whole eigenvalue problem.

My problem however is that this approach is just working for smaller matrices. If the matrices are getting bigger the basis calculated via `NullSpace[]` differes from the "original" eigenvectors.

Here the result from solving the eigenvalue problem:

```
SeedRandom[123];

TestMat = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 4, 6, 8}, {3, 6, 9, 12}, {1, 0, 0, 1}};
Eigenvectors[TestMat] // N


{{13.3007, 26.6015, 39.9022, 1.}, {-0.300735, -0.601471, -0.902206, 1.}, {-2., -3., 0., 2.}, {0., -3., 2., 0.}}
```

Here the approach with `NullSpace[]`:

```
NullSpace[TestMat]

{{-2, -3, 0, 2}, {0, -3, 2, 0}}
```

If I try the same approach with a bigger matrix the procedure fails to compute the eigenvectors from the eigenvalue problem associated with the eigenvalue 0.

```
TestMat2 = 
  Join[#*Range[100] & /@ Range[10], 
   ResourceFunction["RandomMatrix"][
    Real, {0, 100}, {90, 100}]];

EV = Eigenvectors[TestMat2];
EV0Sep = NullSpace[TestMat2];

Norm[Abs@EV0Sep[[#]] - Abs@EV[[91 + #]]]/Norm[EV[[91 + #]]] & /@ 
 Range[Length@EV0Sep]

{0.909716, 0.903307, 0.807493, 0.764305, 0.665924, 0.634019, 0.776413, 0.815826, 0.634899}
```

`TestMat2` is just a random matrix with nine linear dependant columns so I end up getting nine 0-eigenvalues. As you can see in the last calculation there is a significant difference between the eigenvectors calculated with `Eigenvectors[TestMat2]` and `NullSpace[TestMat2]`.

Did I make a mistake or is there a possibility to calculate the NullSpace manually? (`LinearSolve[TestMat2,ConstantArray[0,Length@TestMat2]]` does not work unfortunatly)

Comment: The eigenvector directions are not unique when the eigenspace has dimension larger than one.

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Help  SingularValueDecomposition

```
       TestMat2 =  Join[#*Range[100] & /@ Range[10], 
                        ResourceFunction["RandomMatrix"][
                                Real, {0, 100}, {90, 100}]];        

      {u, \[Sigma], v} = SingularValueDecomposition[TestMat2];

       u . \[Sigma] . Transpose[v] - TestMat2 //Chop//Flatten//Union
          {0}
```

It suffices to calculate the null space of the two right factors

```
        ns = NullSpace[\[Sigma] . Transpose[v]];

        Dimensions[TestMat2]   
           {100,100}


        Dimensions[ns]   
           {9,100}
```

The basis of the nullspace is orthnormal

```
        ns . (ns\[Transpose]) // Chop
             IdentityMatrix[9]
```

numerical errors are of order of $MachinePrecision 10^-14

```
        TestMat2 . (ns \[Transpose]) // Chop // Flatten // Union
            {0}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution but unfortunately this does not fix my problem. The approach by using `NullSpace[]` yields the same result as your approach with the SVD since `NullSpace[]` also gives a orthonormal basis for the nullspace. My goal was to calculate the eigenvectors associated with the 0-eigenvalue from the EWP due to the fact that they span the nullspace of the matrix but as Daniel already mentioned in the comments: the direction of the eigenvectors are not unique if the eigenspace has a dimension larger than one. But thanks again for your help.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your problem, The kernel of a linear map is a vector space, given by a basis. as in any case with degenerate eigenvalues The choice of the basis for that subspace  is algorithm-dependent. In a  physical problem, the choice of the basis of a degeneration subspace  is given by a disturbing  additional matrix, that lifts the degeneration, ega small external field or  the pair interaction between particle partitions of the dimensions in vectors of three coordinates.

Comment: Can this additional matrix then be used to transform the basis given by `NullSpace[]` or `SingularValueDecomposition[]` to the eigenvectors associated with the eigenvalue 0?

Comment: Degenerate nullspaces are a topic of topology. In physics they arise eg, if the manifold carrrying the model allows of linear independent constant vector fields in the kernel of the $\nabla$ operator. Degeneration of non-null energy levels of a matrix approximation of the $H=-Laplacian+V$ circus in a given truncated basis is simply done by series expansions of eigenvalues in terms of a small, asymmetric disturbation $V\to V + \epsilon $\delta V$ . This is the hell of the calculation of perturbations, a bookkeepers or tensor space adminstrators profession.